# Dump HBase database to a different cluster via NiFi

Tags: hbase, apache-nifi

I'm able to migrate HBase tables from one cluster to another via NiFi. But that is at table level and that too if and only if the destination cluster has the table created in HBase.

I want to dump all tables in HBase along with it's schema. Is it possible in the first place? Can someone share some idea if there is any workaround to achieve this?

**Note:**
I can't use the snapshot feature from HBase as both the clusters are not pingable. I have to dump a file in some bridge server and then to the destination cluster. This makes things a bit complex

Comment: I believe when you say both clusters are not pingable, you mean they both reside in different virtual networks. If that's the case, peering them with each other at least till the copying gets done via snapshots would be the better approach. Most of the cloud providers allow VNet peering.

Comment: It can't be done. There are some company's/client's policies which do not allow us. We are using a bridge server which communicates with both the server. The migration has to happen via this bridge server only.
Wondering why the snapshot can't be downloaded to HDFS?